# Organize Webparts in a Hierarchy

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm wondering if it is possible to organize web parts into folders similar to a file library?

An example of this organization would be a number of HR graphs I have in web parts in a single page:

```
Salary1.webpart
Salary2.webpart
Position1.webpart
Position2.webpart
Department1.webpart
Department2.webpart
```

I want to make it so when you click on this page it instead shows you three folders:

```
Salary
Position
Department
```

Where each folder contains the web parts in them:

```
Salary> 
        Salary1.webpart
        Salary2.webpart
Position>
          Position1.webpart
          Position2.webpart
Department>
          Department1.webpart
          Department2.webpart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to organize the web parts into folders, so the best solution I found was to create a page for each step in hierarchy and finally one for the web part.

First page had the following text:

```
Salary
Position
Department
```

Where each links to a page that lists the web part types.  For example, if you clicked on "Salary":

```
Salary1
Salary2
```

Where Salary1 and Salary2 are descriptions of the web parts that each link to a new page with the web part on it.  If you now were to click on Salary1, you would be taken to a new page that contains the Salary1 webpart.